# Python - "random" error

Tags: python

I am writing a code in Python 3.3.3 that makes a list of 32 teams if you enter say 12 and makes sure that the team that is repeated the most is only repeated once more than that which is being repeated the least. If have done this:

```
    import random
    teams =[]
    randoms = []
    team = 0
    amount = 1
    while team != "done":
        team = input("Please enter team name " + str(amount) +" or enter 'done' if you have finished.\n")
        if team != "done":
            teams.append(team)
            randoms.append(team)
            amount = amount + 1
    length = len(teams)
    times =0
    while len(teams) != 32:
        while len(teams) <= 32-length:
            for x in range (0,length+1):
                teamname = teams[x]
                teams.append(teamname)
        else:
           choice = random.choice(randoms)
           teams.append(choice)
           randoms.remove(choice)
        teams.sort()
    for x in range(0,len(teams)):
        print (teams[x])
```

I run the program and enter 12 teams then done. 
It comes up with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 248, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 224, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[File location]", line 30, in <module>
    choice = random.choice(randoms)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\random.", line 250, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

What does this mean and how do I fix this?

Comment: I would assume that randoms is an empty list when you are passing it to random.choice

Comment: Could you sort out your code and traceback indentation, thanks

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Why don't you just do e.g. `(teams * 3)[:32]` (you can calculate the `3` using `math.ceil`) then `random.shuffle` the result?

Comment: @Noelkd is right: `randoms` is empty. Or rather, `randoms` becomes empty after removing all the team names, but then you still have one last loop in your outer `while`. You're updating `teams` in your for-loop, you probably should also update `randoms` there.

Answer (score -1):

That error occurs when the array in the random.choice() function is empty.  I suggest you use a Python Debugger to figure out when the array is completely empty.  It may help you to add a line of code to print len(teams) every loop to see where your coding is messing up.  It may be as simple as > versus >=.

Hope this helps!